# SSRS Combine multiple group instances SQL Server Reporting Services-Grouping

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, grouping, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have the following SQL Server Report:

Bananas
    ---     Green ---  5
      ---   Yellow  ---    10
       ---  Brown    ---   1

Apples
    ---    Red     ---     5
     ---   Gold    ---     7
     ---   Green   ---     2
Carrots
   ---     Orange   ---    4
    ---    Brown    ---    8
Potatoes
   ---     White      ---  3
    ---    Brown      ---  11

How do I go from that to this:
Fruit
--- Green ----7
--- Yellow ---10
--- Brown------1
--- Red--- ----5
--- Gold - - - 7
Vegetables
---Orange---4
---Brown---19
---White---3

Do I need to create a parent group(in the tablix) with a group by expression such as =IIF([Fields!FruitType].Value LIKE "Bananas" LIKE "Apples", "Fruit", "Vegetables")?

Comment: are you saying that didn't work?  (syntax nothwithstanding)

Comment: It did not work. The expression I suggested is what I thought would have been the solution so maybe it is missing something important or there may be a different way to accomplish the joining of groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... Creating the the input data

```
SELECT  Type = 'Bananas' ,Color = 'Green' ,Total= 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bananas'  , 'Yellow', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bananas'  , 'Brown' , 1  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Apples'   , 'Red'   , 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Apples'   , 'Gold'  , 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Apples'   , 'Green' , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carrots'  , 'Orange', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carrots'  , 'Brown' , 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Potatoes' , 'White' , 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Potatoes' , 'Brown' , 11
```

rather than creating a group with that statement, Create a derived column in your resultset (or you could do it in TSQL?)

[image]

Then Create your group...

[image]

then preview...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to accomplish it without changing the query but your solution works great